# Are 302 redirects visible to the final destination?

Tags: http, redirection

Consider the following scenario:

Both `https://foo` and `https://bar` redirects the user's web browser to `https://destination` using the `Location` header with HTTP response code `302`

My question is, is it possible at the `https://destination` server to recognize, through which server the traffic is redirected from?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the question can't be answered clearly, as it depends on exact configuration of a website and the user-agent (browser) used. Long story short: if `destination` owner does not control `foo` or `bar` - then it might be very difficult, if it does - it's easy for the developers to implement.

First of all, you need to specify *how* the `destination` server is expected to recognize the request origin. Just a couple of ways (not closed list) here are:

- by `Referer` header;
- by GET/POST parameters;
- by cookies;
- by some more complex and unclear logic.

### Referer

For `Referer`, the answer is the same as for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string), just with the [newer HTTP RFC document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-referer) to consult with.

Long story short:

- if both `foo` and `bar` **explicitly** set the `Referer` header (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158283/will-a-302-redirect-maintain-the-referer-string)) - it will probably be present in the request to `destination` (it depends upon the user agent though);
- if initial page is retrieved via secured connection, and redirection page is retrieved via unsecure connection - user agent shall not include the header;
- if nothing is explicitly specified, then this is upon the user agent's discretion. Many browsers are likely to not include the header, but this is not guaranteed and can change between versions, as RFC does not mandate the behavior here.

### GET/POST parameters

If all the servers' owners are aligned, they can use GET/POST parameters to pass the origin information to `destination`, as described in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890816/302-redirect-and-referrer-information).

### Cookies

If all the servers' owners are aligned, they can use cookies or even some sort of user tracking mechanisms like Google analytics - there might be a way to utilize this knowledge in order to understand where this user came from.

### Other options

If `destination` owner is not having any means to access or influence `foo` and `bar` servers, he might still be able to deduce some data from the request by checking all the headers and fields carefully - there is a small chance that `foo` and `bar` are, for example, setting some different headers, or redirecting the user to slightly different pages, or exhibiting some other behavior that would allow to track the origin. But this is, of course, not a reliable, if at all possible, solution.

Comment: How can the server set `Referer` header? That's a client-header. And how can they use cookies to track cross site?

Comment: @Alex thanks you for spending your time for the explanation +1 for that. I'm also not convinced about the Referrer header. So, going through the answer what I get is, in a "normal" scenario, it's not possible for the destination to figure out the redirects without additional work at the request side.